# Customizable product with 360 view

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

To the point: I have been assigned to develop a working demo of customizable shoes as seen [here](http://www.vans.com/customizer.html?sku=p_20323&recipe=003&audience=mens). Additional requirement includes swapping of different parts. For example, remove the top part of the shoes and include straps instead or choose from a variety of soles with different heights. (This is a patented product with new locking system. Basically the shoe is comprised of different parts locked together. You can customize the same shoes into sandals also.) Is the concept of drag and drop feasible here using 3d object models, gsap and three.js? The website should be responsive also. I'm sailing on uncharted waters here. So tips, suggestions, workarounds, anything is welcome.

Comment: You'd need to have the individual shoe parts as separate 3d models aligned to fit at their borders. The different part variants (e.g. models of different sole height) can then be loaded to the scene and moved around or shown/hidden in the scene. It's feasible, you just need to have the 3D models done right.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking about, or what it is that you want to achieve. What should be dragged and dropped where? Should the model be live-updated while dragging? Or just parts being replaced once they are dropped? I'd recommend to start very simple, just figuring out the 3D-models and rendering them in proper visual quality is in itself challenging enough...

Comment: I was thinking about placing those different parts in a side panel and the actual object model (base model of the shoe) to be modified inside a container. The user can drag the parts into the container and on drop event reload the object model inside the container showing the now customized product (that's what the client asked).